# Comparing data of two textboxes is not working using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to compare the data of two text boxes using jquery like as we compare the password and confirm password while making an email account. Still i have the following stuff.

**CSS**

```
.test {
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="t1" />
<input type="text" name="t2" />
<label class="test" name="lblerror">Error</label>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#t2").click(function () {
    if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()) {} else {
        $("#lblerror").removeClass("test");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MtPeZ/)

Please help me, how can i compare these two strings while just leaving the second text box named `t2`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not know some basics about html and javaScript. You need to start from the beginning.

Comment: @B.K. true perhaps, but not helpful. Everyone begins somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

You are using name as  Id in Jquery, it is wrong. convert name to id. then it will work.

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<label class="test" id="lblerror">Error</label>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#t2").change(function () {
                 if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()) {
                    $("#lblerror").addClass("test");        
                }
                else {
                    $("#lblerror").removeClass("test");
                }
            });
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MtPeZ/16/)

Comment: . I want to ask a thing that is where i have to use this code in header of the master page or just after these two textboxes

Answer (score 1):

In your html

```
<input type="text" name="t1" />
    <input type="text" name="t2" />
```

You haven'nt provided ID's

Your code Should be

```
<input type="text" name="t1"  id="t1" />
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"  />
```

More over you need to add `blur` event I guess.

```
$("#t2").blur(function () {
                    if ($("#t1").val() == $("#t2").val()) {
                      $("#lblerror").removeClass("test");
                    }
                    else {
                       $("#lblerror").addClass("test");  
                    } 
                });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/MtPeZ/35/)

Answer (score 1):

`$("#t2")` would refer to an element with `id="t2"` but all your fields have only `name` and no `id`. You should add an `id` to the fields to access it.

Try changing your HTML code to be something like the below:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<label class="test" id="lblerror">Error</label>
```

You can use the below code to then compare the value of the two fields and then show/hide the label error based on the comparison result.

```
$("#t2").on("blur", function () {
    if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()) {
        $("#lblerror").hide();
    } else {
        $("#lblerror").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the element by $("#t1") t1 should be the id, not the name.

Add id="t1" to the input tag.

```
<input type="text" name="t1"  id="t1" />
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
   if ($('#textbox1').val() === $('#textbox2').val()) {
     alert('values match');
     evt.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

uses the .submit() method to bind to the submit event for the form, then compares the 2 values from the textboxes - if they are the same it displays an alert then prevents the default action (form submission) using event.preventDefault()

[**Working example demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/AYrud/)

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute cannot be used as a selector this way. Moreover, in your jquery you have used "#" which selects an element on the basis of its id. Change your HTML as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<label class="test" id="lblerror">Error</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to id instead of name and blur event instead of click

Click requires you to click it again after entering

```
$("#t2").blur(function () {



                        if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()) {
                         $("#lblerror").removeClass("test");

                        }
                        else {
                           $("#lblerror").addClass("test");    

                        }


    });
```